# PHP Concatenate variable inside statement

Tags: php

Ok I've been up all weekend and apparently my brain has imploded - I just can't conquer something that should be easy I think:

Using PHP.  I have a variable:

```
$pageid = 9999;
```

and I have a template page full of hundreds of statements, like:

```
<?php $simplex->menu( 200029999, 200009999,1); ?>
```

(The 9999 is at the end of each number in every case)

In all of these statements, I need to replace the 9999 with the variable $pageid so that this number is no longer hardcoded (figuring to bulk replace using notepad++).

But for some reason I can't come up with a working syntax and my attempts to find an example here are failing too.  Any hints appreciated!!

UPDATE for clarification:

In the end I want the statement to have $pageid coded into it, i.e.

```
<?php $simplex->menu( 20002'.$pageid.', 20000'.$pageid.',1); ?>
```

Obviously my above example is complete FUBAR but just trying to illustrate the end result I'm trying to achieve... then whatever value is assigned to $pageid will be applied to the statement itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to me that you want to refactor your code. This might seem hard to do with search/replace but your line could look something like this:

```
<?php $simplex->menu( intval('20002'.$pageid), intval('20000'.$pageid), 1); ?>
```

This way you can later change the value of `$pageid` and everything will work.

To replace this in notepadd++ use regex: find `(\d+)9999,` replace with  `intval('\1'.$pageid),` and check Regular expression option.
Here's the screenshot [image: screenshot]

Comment: Kosta, THIS WORKS - AWESOME!  I ran it on one page to verify, then on all 34 pages in the project... replacing a total 4,412 occurrences - and flipping through the pages they all appear to function perfectly!!! of course I will comb through to verify no anomalies, but no way I would have figured this out, thanks so much ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This assumes there are no other occurances of 9999

```
$new_var = str_replace('9999',$pageid,$yourvar_with_the_9999);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - my question may not have been clear - or I am just not approaching this correctly - I need to actually insert the variable code (i.e. 'something'.$pageid.'something') into the statement itself... so that when the variable $pageid pulls it's value from mysql, that value will be injected throughout the page where the 9999 is currently... hope that makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Notepad++ Regex driven replace engine (If I got the question right):

Replace `(\d+)9999 *,` with `\1'.$pageid.',`

Edit: The asterisk on the beginning was nonsense.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the response... yes, that is (conceptually) the method I plan to use, although your suggestion is better constructed... but my problem has been that in every case the resulting statements fail - in otherwords I can't seem to insert the .$pageid. into those statements in a way that in which the statements actually function...